# I need to animate depth-first-search algorithm in python for my assignment but being a beginner I have no idea where to start

Tags: python, c++, depth-first-search

I just need a basic animation showing how the nodes are visited in the algorithm. I tried searching the internet but nothing seems to be that helpful. Any references or similar projects will be highly appreciated. If there's a way to do it in C++, that would be great too.

Comment: What kind of animation did you have in mind?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.